# How to create a new passwordSignupFields in accounts-base package?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

This is the default settings for the fields when creating an account. How do I create my own passwordSignupFields? For an example I want to have a user have to enter in an address when creating an account.

`passwordSignupFields String`

Which fields to display in the user creation form. One of:

- `'USERNAME_AND_EMAIL'`
- `'USERNAME_AND_OPTIONAL_EMAIL'`
- `'USERNAME_ONLY'`
- `'EMAIL_ONLY'` (default).

(accounts-ui-unstyled/accounts_ui.js, line 27)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to remove `accounts-ui` package and add package `ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3`.  Here you can add as many fields as you like with a variety of fields like a radio button, select dropdown, text fields etc.

To make your work  easy, in `client\main.js` you can copy paste below code and try your ways,

```
Accounts.ui.config({
    passwordSignupFields: "USERNAME_AND_EMAIL",
    forceEmailLowercase: true,
    forceUsernameLowercase: true,
    forcePasswordLowercase: true,
    extraSignupFields: [{
          fieldName: 'name',
          fieldLabel: 'Full Name',
          inputType: 'text',
          visible: true,
          validate: function(value, errorFunction) {
            if (!value) {
              errorFunction("Please provide valid Full Name [Max - 50 Characters]");
              return false;
            } else {
              return true;
            }
          }
      }, {
        fieldName: 'mobile',
        fieldLabel: 'Mobile Number',
        inputType: 'text',
        visible: true,
        validate: function(value, errorFunction) {
          if (!value) {
            errorFunction("Please provide valid Mobile Number.");
            return false;
          } else {
            return true;
          }
        }
    }
    ]
});
```

When you see on UI, it will look like this,

[image]

For more info:

https://github.com/ianmartorell/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3/blob/master/README.md